# Copying non-compiled files using Maven

Tags: java, maven

I'm making a web app using, among other things, Maven and Hibernate. My project structure looks something like this:

```
project-root
    src
        main
            java
                com.projectname
                    persistence
                        hibernate
                            mappings
                                table.hbm.xml
                            HibernateDAO.java
```

Right now Maven builds the java files and recreates the folder structure necessary for the .class files, but ignores moving hbm.xml files.

Other solutions I've found that don't quite work mention either redirecting the resources destination (which seems to be an all or nothing solution: some resources should exist inside WEB-INF, but not all) or using the ANT copy thing inside Maven which is looking more complicated by the minute.

So how do I get my hbm.xml files into my output?

Comment: That is precisely what `resources` means. (And if you're working on a new project that has `WEB-INF` _or_ `hbm.xml`, you're using obsolete tooling.)

Comment: The standard way would be to have these files in `src/main/resources`. That should work out of the box (they are added to the classpath and included in build artifacts).